# WPF Bug with custom fonts

Tags: wpf, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF Custom fonts problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516639/wpf-custom-fonts-problem)

I have a project with custom font that used to show the right fonts. One day I compiled (no changes) and fonts were gone, and there's no evident way to get them back because absolutely nothing in the project changed.

Has anyone seen this before, or can think of any solution?

Thanks.